# Looking for suggestions on performing a complex csv to json data flow transformation

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction to perform the following data transformation in Azure Data Factory.

Source Data (CSV) in Blob Storage:

| SKU_ID | TITLE | COLOR | SIZE | PRODUCT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123-1 | Shirt | Blue | Small | 123 |
| 123-2 | Shirt | Blue | Medium | 123 |
| 123-3 | Shirt | Blue | Large | 123 |
| 456-1 | Hoodie | Black | Small | 456 |
| 456-2 | Hoodie | Black | Medium | 456 |
| 456-3 | Hoodie | Black | Large | 456 |

Each sku_id should be grouped together in the final JSON output by product_id.

Transformed to JSON for storage in Comos DB:

```
[
    {
        "product_id": "123",
        "title": "Shirt",
        "variants": [
            {
                "sku_id": "123-1",
                "color": "Blue",
                "size": "Small"
            },
            {
                "sku_id": "123-2",
                "color": "Blue",
                "size": "Medium"
            },
            {
                "sku_id": "123-3",
                "color": "Blue",
                "size": "Large"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "product_id": "456",
        "title": "Hoodie",
        "variants": [
            {
                "sku_id": "456-1",
                "color": "Black",
                "size": "Small"
            },
            {
                "sku_id": "456-2",
                "color": "Black",
                "size": "Medium"
            },
            {
                "sku_id": "456-3",
                "color": "Black",
                "size": "Large"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Is this too complex to handle with Azure Data Factory?

Any suggestion on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rough DSL script snippet for dataflow before you write it to cosmosdb

products aggregate(
groupBy(productId, title),
variants = collect(@(skuId = skuId, color = color, size = size))
) ~> productAggregate

Comment: can you provide any additional detail on how to build this flow?

Comment: aggregate is aggregate transform,
product is the source,

groupBy is in aggregate settings,
Under columns tab you will add a new column 'variants' and type the expression to the right

Comment: Thank you I was able to figure it out. Unfortunately, the real data may not be as consistent (title etc.) as the contrived data about. Thank you for your help, very much appreciated.

Comment: I'm noticing the aggregate process is taking extremely long, 30 rows down to 6 rows is taking 6 minutes. Any suggestions on speeding this up?